# MD5 hash in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, md5

I am working on a Windows phone 7 application. I am using [this implementation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMD5) for MD5 hashing in silverlight.

I am using this code -

```
    protected string GetMD5Hash(string input)
    {
        byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        MD5Managed md5 = new MD5Managed();
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(bs);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in bs)
        {
            sb.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
        }

        return sb.ToString();    
    }
```

But, I am not getting the correct MD5 hash for the input I provide. I am not sure what is wrong with this code. If anyone has used  [this implementation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMD5) for MD5 hashing in silverlight, do you know where have I gone wrong?

Comment: As a note, MD5 could well be considered obsolete by now - it is not secure. I'd recommend using an implementation of the SHA family.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? What are you comparing it with? There are comments on the page you link to that say it is buggy and should not be used

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment I am working with a 3rd party API and so its really not up to me to decide.

Comment: @Matt Lacey Yeah I saw those comments. But I didn't find anything else when I looked for alternatives except for doing it myself from scratch. And many threads, even in stackoverflow suggested this implementation. How I got to know its wrong? Typically a MD5 hash is represented as a sequence of 32 hexadecimal digits but for certain inputs I got more.

Comment: I can't find MD5Managed on a Windows Phone 7 app.

Comment: What is the namespace of `MD5Managed`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're returning the hex version of the *input*, not the hash:

```
foreach (byte b in bs)
```

should be

```
foreach (byte b in hash)
```

(An alternative is to use `Convert.ToBase64String(hash)` if you don't mind it being in Base64 rather than hex.)

Comment: @Pavanred Well, you can get Rubber ducky to stop feeling silly :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 4):

There is already an accepted answer for this, but for others who are using MD5 in Silverlight or Windows Phone, I'm posting a link to [another implementation](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/03/silverlight-2-md5/) of MD5 that I've had more success with.

I spent several hours beating my head against the wall with the implementation mentioned by the original post, trying to get it working in my Windows Phone project. It was working in some cases and not in others.

Jeff Wilcox's version worked perfectly.